# Erro de indentificador invalido SQL (INNER JOIN)

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

2. Selecione uma lista de empregados que trocaram de cargo ou departamento (`job_history`), a lista deve
   conter a matricula e nome do empregado, o nome do departamento e cargo que trabalhou, e também a
   data inicio e fim (`start_date` e `end_date`), ordenar pela data início.

Faça um select com inner join utilizando where e outro select com join...on.

R:

```
select 
    E.employee_id, 
    E.first_name||' '||E.last_name "Nome", 
    D.department_name, 
    J.job_title, 
    JH.start_date, 
    JH.end_date
from employees E, job_history JH, jobs J
inner join departments D on E.employee_id = JH.employee_id 
                         and D.department_id = JH.department_id 
                         and J.job_id = JH.job_id
order by JH.start_date;
```

> ORA-00904: "JH"."JOB_ID": identificador inválido
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Erro na linha: 18 Coluna: 114

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: coloca o `job_history` e `jobs` também no `join`

Comment: Erro de sintaxe, veja como fazer inner join com 3 tabelas ou mais.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tente fazer um join para cada relação, tipo.

```
select 
E.employee_id, 
E.first_name||' '||E.last_name "Nome", 
D.department_name, 
J.job_title, 
JH.start_date, 
JH.end_date
from 
employees E inner join departments D on E.department_id = D.department_id,
job_history JH inner join departments D on JH.department_id = 
D.department_id, jobs J inner join departments D on J.department_id = 
D.department_id,
.
.
.
order by JH.start_date;
```